# Parameterized Constructor for Node Based Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I'm in CS2 and we're just learning about linked lists and I have to code the parameterized constructor of a linked list class (node based). I don't really understand the node lists, so any help of what's going on here or how to approach would be helpful! I have the following Node class given:

```
class Node {

friend class NodeList;

public:
 Node() : m_next(NULL) {}
 Node(const DataType& data, Node* next = NULL) :
        m_next(next), m_data(data) {}
 Node(const Node& other) : m_next(other.m_next),
                           m_data(other.m_data) {}

 DataType& data() { return m_data; }

 const DataType& data() const { return m_data; }

private:
 Node* m_next;
 DataType m_data;
};
```

and I'm trying to create the parameterized constructor for the following class:

```
Class NodeList {
    public:
     NodeList();
     NodeList(size_t count, const int value);
    private:
     Node* m_head;
}
```

, where the parameterized constructor is supposed to have 'count' nodes initialized to 'value'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving a problem like this has 3 parts.

- Break the problem down into smaller, simpler tasks that make it easier to solve
- Do the smaller tasks
- Use them to solve the big problem.

**What would make it easy to solve this problem?** Adding one value to a list is easier than adding multiple values to a list, so let's write a function to do that.

To add one value at the beginning of the list,

- We can create a new node with that value
- We have the new node point to the current first node
- We set the current first node to the new node.

Let's call our function `prepend`, since it prepends the value to the list.

```
class NodeList {
   public:
    // The head should be set to null initially
    NodeList() 
      : m_head(nullptr) 
    {
    }
    // This function takes a value and adds it to the beginning of the list
    void prepend(const DataType& value) {
        // The new node uses the current head as the next value
        Node* newNode = new Node(value, m_head); 
        // We set the current head to the new node. 
        m_head = newNode; 
    }
```

Now, adding a value multiple times is easy. We can just call prepend once for each time we want to add an item.

```
class NodeList {
   public:
    // The head should be set to null initially
    NodeList() 
      : m_head(nullptr) 
    {
    }
    // This function takes a value and adds it to the beginning of the list
    void prepend(const DataType& value) {
        // The new node uses the current head as the next value
        Node* newNode = new Node(value, m_head); 
        // We set the current head to the new node. 
        m_head = newNode; 
    }

    NodeList(size_t count, const DataType& value) 
      : m_head(nullptr) // The head still has to be null initially
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {
           prepend(value); 
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!